# how to get local date/time in linux terminal while server configured in UTC/different timezone?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

how to get local date & time in linux terminal while server configured in UTC or different timezone?

here is what I get now but I'd like to see in local timezone. For eg: PST/PDT.

```
[jenkins@myServer ~]$ date
Thu Jul 28 18:16:48 UTC 2016
```

I'm not looking to change system time using hwclock or updating /etc/localtime. Just want to change it for a user.

Also, please let me know - how to persist it for future logins.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `TZ` environment variable to pass the desired timezone to `date`:

```
TZ=<timezone> date
```

You can find the available timezones in the `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` directory and subdirectories. For example, `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York` defines `TZ=America/New_York`.

**Example:**

```
$ date                         
Fri Jul 29 06:31:53 BDT 2016

$ TZ='America/New_York' date   
Thu Jul 28 20:31:58 EDT 2016

$ TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date
Thu Jul 28 17:31:54 PDT 2016
```

Answer (score 4):

For a local time, use "*date*". For UTC time, use "*date -u*". Note that, if you use "date" in the server's terminal it returns the server local time.

Comment: How did this attract the most upvotes? Not only does it not answer the actual question at hand, it suggests to use local time on the server instead. The latter being pretty silly - the convenience of **not** having to set the TZ in one's local shell is fat outweighed by the fact that UTC doesn't have the stupid issue of daylight savings times...

Comment: I agree with @tink, My host/dev box is always set at UTC so all my logs default to UTC so I can compare times across boxes in different timezones.  I'm looking for a way to say based on my current internet provider what time zone am I likely in.  If that doesn't work then I'll just have to hard-code GMT+4 and deal with daylight savings times on a manual basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can show local time by overriding the `TZ` environment variable for the process which prints the date.  [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) a lot about the topic, beginning with

> This variable shall represent timezone information. The contents of the environment variable named **`TZ`** shall be used by the `ctime()`, `ctime_r()`, **`localtime()`**, `localtime_r()` `strftime()`, `mktime()`, functions, and by various utilities, to override the default timezone.

Conventional 3-character timezone values were some time ago (more or less) standardized to deprecate the 3-character forms, using the *combined* standard and daylight savings time form.  The preferred form used for `PDT` is **`PST8PDT`**.

There's a [page on VMware](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112114000/https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/timezone.html) showing the names and mentioning that they are used on Linux; you may notice that very few of those are 3-character form (aside from the generic `UTC`+*offset*).

Further reading:

- [Valid timeZone Values](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112114000/https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/timezone.html) (VMware):
- [IANA - Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I liked the VMWare's **Valid timeZone values** link.

Comment: I'm trying `alias ldate='TZ=America/New_York date'` (on UNIX).  I'm hoping this automatically handles the daylight savings times issue.

Comment: Seems like the VMware links are now broken